# automate sales counter in the model

Tags: python, odoo

I am trying to make an automation in my model through code but I don't know if I am missing something because I add what I found on Google but at the end of a month it is not restored. I wish that through an accountant that I already have the method count the sales made in a month, that currently makes it but at the end of the month it continues adding the sales of the previous month and that I do not want, since the idea is that at the end of a month sales made in a month resume and start at 0. The code I have is as follows:

```xml
<data noupdate = "1">

        <record forcecreate = "True" id = "vendor_monthly_counter" model = "ir.cron">
           <field name = "name"> Monthly worker accountant </field>
           <field eval = "True" name = "active" />
           <field name = "user_id" ref = "base.user_root" />
           <field name = "interval_number"> 1 </field>
           <field name = "interval_type"> months </field>
           <field name = "numbercall"> - 1 </field>
           <field ref = "model_proyecto_rc_trabajador" name = "model_id" />
            <field name = "state"> code </field>
           <field name = "code"> model.get_realized_sales () </field>
           <field eval = "False" name = "doall" />
           <field name = "function"> True </field>
```

**py get_realized_sales**

```py
class worker(models.Model):
    _name = 'project_rc.worker'
    _rec_name = 'name'

    name = fields.Char(string="Name", required=True)
    charge = fields.Selection(
        [('seller', 'Seller'), ('cashier', 'Cashier')],
        string="Cargo", required=True)
    sales_counter = fields.Integer(
        string="Sales made", compute="get_realized_sales", store=True)
    document_ids = fields.One2many(
        comodel_name='project_rc.document', inverse_name='worker_id',
        string='Invoice', required=true)

    @api.depends ('document_ids')
    def get_realized_sales(self):
        for rec in self:
            document = rec.document_ids.filtered(
                lambda r: r.type_movimiento_id and\
                    r.type_movement_id.type_movement == 'sale')
            rec.sales_counter = len(document)
```

What could I miss, some py? and how would that py be?

Comment: You should add the code of `get_realized_sales()`, that's where the logic and the whole calculation is. Nobody can answer the question, when there is simply a bit of code of a cron job record.

Comment: I just added the code where the get_realized_sales

Comment: You should really think about coding guidelines. So many spaces and empty lines in your code, which shouldn't be there when following coding guidelines like PEP8 for python code.

Comment: I'm confused here, you are showing a cron for `proyecto_rc_trabajador` model, the method you posted is in `project_rc.worker` I don't see any filtering condition on dates?!! are you creating a new record every month to hold sales of that month? your question needs a lot of explanation you need to explain what you are doing and you could put all related part of your code

Comment: the code get_realized_sales is a method created to count exclusively the sales made by each worker, but other than that I need to return to 0 at the end of a month and recount the sales for another month.

Comment: This causes you to add the get_realized_sales () to this part of the initial code <field name = "code"> model.get_realized_sales () </field>
but I just realized that the word "model" in the following lines of code are bad since the module is called project_rc then the model is deleted or not? <field ref = "model_proyecto_rc_trabajador" name = "model_id" />
<field name = "code"> model.get_realized_sales () </field>

Comment: I would modify the parts I found that could be wrong like this:
<field ref = "project_rc_worker" name = "model_id" />
<field name = "code"> get_realized_sales () </field>

but in name = "model_id" I don't know what to put

Comment: Still unclear what you want exactly, in model_id you should keep the prefix `model_`,  `model_project_rc_worker` and how many record in this model? Is there only one, and when you create a `document` you atache it to this record? Please edit your question and explain your goal and what Idea you used

Comment: Basically, I wanted the sales counter to return to 0 a month and start again to have the objective of knowing who was the seller who made the most sales in a month, This is achieved by creating a document since it is there if It is a sale for a customer or purchase of the company, also the worker who made that sale gets.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the value in the record of the for loop.

instead of

```py
sales_counter = len(document)
```

use

```py
rec.sales_counter = len(document)
```

Comment: yes, I had it as rec.sales_counter, the problem is that at the end of the month sales are not restored.

Comment: I don't see any date based logic in your code. So why should there be anything restored? Either the `type_movimiento_id` should change after month to another one or you implement a date based logic like getting the current month and filtering the sales by this month (for example current date is 2020-01-31 means current month is 2020-01-01 - 2020-01-31 and the sales have to be in that period).